# What is the scope of type variables?

Tags: generics, swift, scope, type-variables

I hit some confusing error messages from the Swift compiler (`'A' is not convertible to 'A'`, `'E' is not identical to 'E'`) and I think it's because I introduced identically named type variables in two scopes, where one scope was nested inside the other.

I'd like to get a more complete idea of how type variables work, and so I have a few related questions:

- what is the scope of type variables in Swift?
- ow is the scope affected by nested types and methods?
- can type variables be shadowed?
- what happens when a nested method introduces a type variable of the same name as an enclosing class?
- is it possible to do something like `method2` (below)?  (my XCode kept crashing and I wasn't able to figure this out)

Here are a few examples to show what I'm trying to figure out:

```
class MyClass<A> {

    func method1<A>(a:A) -> A {
        // what does A refer to here?
        return a;
    }

    class func staticmethod<A>(a:A) -> A {
        // what does A refer to here?
        return a;
    }

    func method2() -> ((A) -> A) {
        // is this even possible?  
        // I'm not sure how to write method2's type !
        func id<A>(a:A) -> A {
            return a;
        }
        return id;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the generic type of a generic class/struct/method/function is exactly
the class/struct/method/function. And yes, it can be shadowed by nested definitions.

In your example, `A` in `method1` is the generic type for that method and will
be replaced by the actual type when the method is called. It shadows the generic
type of `MyClass<A>`. Example:

```
let mc = MyClass<Int>()      // class instantiated with actual type Int
let x = mc.method1("foo")    // method called with actual type String
println(x) // "foo"
```

The same is true for the static method:

```
let y = MyClass<Int>.staticmethod(123.5) // method called with type Double
println(y)
```

In your `method2`, the inner function does not get a type parameter, it should be
(and I have removed one pair of unnecessary parentheses):

```
func method2a() -> (A) -> A {
    func id(a:A) -> A {
        return a;
    }
    return id;
}
```

or

```
func method2b<A>() -> (A) -> A {
    func id(a:A) -> A {
        return a;
    }
    return id;
}
```

depending on whether it works with the type of the class or introduces its own
generic type. Note that you can shorten that using a closure instead of an
nested function, e.g.

```
func method2b<A>() -> (A) -> A {
    return { a in a }
}
```

In the first case you would use it like

```
let mc = MyClass<Int>()    // class instantiated with type Int, therefore 
let z = mc.method2a()(12)   // mc.method2a() has signature Int -> Int
println(z)
```

and in the second case you could do

```
let mc = MyClass<Int>()   // class instantiated with type Int, but
let z = mc.method2b()("bar") // mc.method2b() has signature String -> String
println(z)
```

Here the actual type of `method2b<A>` is inferred from the argument "bar" as `String`.

Generally, I would prefer to use different names for nested generic types
to avoid unnecessary confusion.